# How to derive the values of a Typescript type from the keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can we define the type of the values of an object based on the value of it's key?

I tried to do the following. However, it doesn't seem to be valid syntax:

```js
type Config = {
    [Arg: string]: (arg: `Test-${Arg}`) => void
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please give us some examples of what these objects can look like? It's unclear to me what "values of an object based on the value of it's key" means.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make this fully general. You'll certainly need to type the actual keys in one place or another.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without using a type variable.

```
type Config<A extends string> = {
  [K in A]: (arg: `Test-${K}`) => void
}

type X = 'Foo' | 'Bar'

const asConfig = <A extends string>(c: Config<A>): Config<A> => c

const config = asConfig({
  Foo: foo => {
    foo // 'Test-Foo'
  },
  Bar: bar => {
    bar // 'Test-Bar'
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAglCAPYCBAEwGcpTgAnFBNAPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKWlCwBdAFxQAFAEMqacQAMAKhEoBaACSteAX3kBKZowBucFMXbb27UJCgANZlADkAMThwnUAD7OAQjKcrAGNESigpUnhkdEdsXAIiMgpqWgYJIPEo1Ewsej1MxGzsRiZGIODQ4CgQ6LRHCKz0CQ4uNzhxJHdDNk4uKE64KAB6IedlNTbArm0AGl7-KnEAIxlulr6VqmHRp3HgVQWpqEttPXYgA)

EDIT: updated with a suggestion from jcalz.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without indicating the keys in the config type?

Comment: You may want to suggest making a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGnQKm), so that the compiler can *infer* the generic type parameter instead of requiring the developer to specify it manually.

Comment: That seems to work! I would mark it as the accepted answer if you submitted it as an answer. However, I don't understand how we're casting an object to a string…